# How to link button to drop down list with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I am in the process of working on a donation page for a website that has a form where, among other things, the user can select a specific child to sponsor from a drop down list.

One thing that I had thought about was having a different donation button for each child on their bio page that brings the user to the same donation form. I have been trying to find out if it is possible to customize each button so that it is associated with that particularly child in the drop down list on the form, but haven't had much luck.

In other words, I want multiple buttons on one page that brings you to the form on a second page. If you click the button for child one, it brings you to the form, but with kid one auto populated in the drop down list.

Is this possible? If not, is it possible to have the kid's name auto populate in a textbox instead?

Below is a sample of what the drop down list currently looks like, if it helps:

```
<style>
  select:invalid {
    color: gray;
  }
</style>
<select name="children" required style="font-size:16px;height:25px">
  <option value="placeholder" selected disabled>Please select</option>
  <option value="child one">Child One</option>
  <option value="child two">Child Two</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why dont you just post it and catch it on another page?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to link buttons from page one to a dropdown on page two? Why not just adding parameters to the url and either process them with server side language (php, python...) or with javascript on page load.